# Round Dash (Dot) MapPolyline in HereMaps SDK

Tags: android, here-api

Android Google Maps SDK  provides a way to create round/dot (dash)  Polylines ([Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline)). Is there a way to do this in HereMaps? The API seems to support only square/rectangular pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash is supported, `setDashEnabled`, and a round cap style `CapStyle#ROUND`, but specifically round segments of the dashed line are not supported. You could try to reduce the dash length to get a similar aesthetic `setDashPrimaryLength`, `setDashSecondaryLength`.